# how to remove duplicate array value from multidimensional associative array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-unique

contains the following i am trying get array_unique value from multidimensional associative array

Here, i am only showing only sample array which is similar to this.

```
$array =  ['games'=>[['vollyball', 'football'], ['vollyball', 'football'], ['rubby', 'chess']]];
```

Here is tried so for

```
foreach ($array as $key => &$value) {
    $value = array_unique($value);
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";
exit;
```

Here i am expecting output is,

```
 $array =  ['games'=>[['vollyball', 'football'], ['rubby', 'chess']]];
```

Here the array should be same even after removing duplicate from multidimensional array.

Thanks for your time and suggestions.

Comment: Are you trying to filter out duplicates to be left with a unique array or...?

Comment: your expected output?

Comment: @Script47, i am trying to filter out duplicates to be left

Comment: @VijayaKrishna Sorry, but that confused me even more, you can either filter out duplicates or leave them in, but not '*filter out duplicates to be left*'.

Comment: @Script47, i am updated my question please check it once

Comment: @devpro, i am updated my question, Please check it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try the following:

```
$a=array_values(array_unique(array_merge(...$array['games'])));
```

This assumes that all your usable values are below `$array['games']`.

**Edit:**

Here is another way, using `array_walk`:

```
array_walk($array['games'],function($itm){global $res; $res[json_encode($itm)]=$itm;});

echo json_encode(array_values($res));
```

I don't like the global `$res` array very much, but this is a way forward, I believe. In the callback function of `array_walk()` I add all values to an associative array (`$res`). The keys are JSON representations of their actual values. This way I will overwrite identical values in the associative array `$res` and will end up with a set of unique values when I apply the `array_values()` function at the end to turn it back into a non-associative array.

The result is:

```
[["vollyball","football"],["rubby","chess"]]
```

Here is a little demo you can check out: http://rextester.com/JEKE60636

**2. edit**

Using a wrapper function I can now do without the global variable `$res` and do the operation in-place, i. e. removing duplicate elements directly from the source array:

```
function unique(&$ag){
 array_walk($ag,function($itm,$key) use (&$ag,&$res) {
     if (isset($res[json_encode($itm)]))  array_splice($ag,$key,1);
     else                                 $res[json_encode($itm)]=1.;
 });
}

unique($array['games']);

echo json_encode($array)
```

This will result in

```
{"games":[["vollyball","football"],["rubby","chess"]]}
```

see here: http://rextester.com/YZLEK39965

Comment: Hi @cars10m, thanks for the answer, but i am not to merge the array_values, the array should be same after removing duplicate

Comment: Yes, I read the comments to your question ... (after I posted this) ;-)

Comment: Ok thanks, @cars10m, is it possible to remove duplicates from multidimensional array